# How to solve -lpcre2-8 error while installing rJava package in R?

Tags: r, rjava

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.all:35: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpxlbMFl/R.INSTALLeb81ff01ac6/rJava/jri/src'
Makefile.all:19: recipe for target 'src/JRI.jar' failed
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpxlbMFl/R.INSTALLeb81ff01ac6/rJava/jri'
Makevars:14: recipe for target 'jri' failed
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/gurjar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rJava’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpXFYJ9B/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there any libraries I might be missing while hammering the same code for installation?

Comment: It looks like you might need to install the pcre2 library from here ftp://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/, compile them, and then try re-installing the library.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer installing the pcer2 works, I use the steps specified on the main site of the library http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre2.html

1 st:

```html
Download (HTTP): [https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre2-10.36.tar.bz2][1]
OR Download (FTP): [ftp://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre2-10.36.tar.bz2][2]
```

2 nd:

```html
./configure --prefix=/usr                       \
            --docdir=/usr/share/doc/pcre2-10.36 \
            --enable-unicode                    \
            --enable-jit                        \
            --enable-pcre2-16                   \
            --enable-pcre2-32                   \
            --enable-pcre2grep-libz             \
            --enable-pcre2grep-libbz2           \
            --enable-pcre2test-libreadline      \
            --disable-static                    &&
make
```

3 rd

```html
make install
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.